# LEGO Mindstorms 9797 (NXT Education base set) Software Download

Tags: mindstorms, nxt

Where I can download the Software for the LEGO Mindstorms 9797 (NXT Education base set)

Answer (score 8):

I contacted Lego and they gave me this link for a PC:

https://fileshare.corp.lego.com/node_share_links/119233?token=7a9527d5-cd94-491c-88b3-689587eae5ae
I don't have the link for a Mac, but you can ask Lego for it.

Comment: Very nice! This should be the accepted answer. Welcome to Bricks.SE!

Answer (score 5):

As of 2021, the retail version of the NXT software is still available for download from [the  official LEGO MINDSTORMS download page](https://www.lego.com/en-us/themes/mindstorms/downloads) (near the bottom of the page).

The Education version of the software is available on the [retired products download page](https://education.lego.com/en-us/downloads/retiredproducts/nxt/software).

Comment: Or you can download the EV3 Software (Home or Education) and use this for programming the NXT (but with limitations).

Answer (score 2):

The software is now available for download (Win/Mac) on LEGO Education [site](https://education.lego.com/en-us/downloads/retiredproducts/nxt/software).